# Why are monofilar coils not used in helicon plasmas?

Tags: plasma-physics

I've been looking into helicon plasma sources, and what I've found is that there are multiple different antenna shapes (loop, double half-loop, Boswell, Nagoya-III, half-helix, etc.). However, I haven't seen much done with the relatively common ICP monofilar helical antenna. What I have seen has been with the application of a static, axial magnetic, but this results in an opposite change in performance (i.e. electron density) compared to a "standard" helicon plasma.

What has been particularly difficult to find in any of the literature is the answer to "why?" Why is a helicon wave capable of being launched with the other antennas but not a multi-loop (helical) antenna? What makes those antennas special? This is especially confusing because a single-loop antenna has been used to launch helicon waves with great success.

Further, while it is explained very clearly why the on-axis electron density decreases with increasing strength of the magnetic field, it doesn't seem to explain why the overall electron density increases along with the electron temperature for helicon plasmas despite producing a similar radial change in electron distribution.

The monofilar ICP antennas have great inductive coupling. Their RF coupling efficiency in the inductive (H) mode is significantly better than the antennas used for helicons. Does the strength of the RF inductive coupling play a role in the initiation of a helicon (W) mode plasma? More succinctly, does a strong RF inductive field suppress helicon waves?

references:
"Comparison of the B field dependency of plasma parameters of a weakly magnetized inductive and Helicon hydrogen discharge" [Briefi 2016]

"Effects of axial magnetic field on discharge characteristics of inductively coupled plasma" [Zhang 2020]

"Impact of Internal Faraday Shields on RF Driven Hydrogen Discharges" [Rauner 2022]

Answer (score 0):

From Miljak & Chen: Helicon wave excitation with rotating antenna fields

> **Abstract**. By using phased bifilar antennas, helicon waves have been
> excited by applying fields which rotate either in space or in time, or
> both simultaneously. The direction of rotation is made to favour
> either m = +1 or m = −1 waves, where m is the azimuthal mode number,
> and m is measured directly. Rotation in time is found to be more
> effective than rotation in space and makes possible a direct
> comparison of m = ±1 excitation. An m = −1 structure was seen only in
> the antenna near field, while m = +1 modes propagate far downstream.
> Up to 2 kW of RF power, density profiles and antenna loading
> measurements show that m < 0 (left-hand) waves are poorly coupled, and
> m = +1 (right-hand) waves are necessary for good plasma production.
> Loading results indicate that antennas also couple to absorption
> mechanisms unrelated to helicon waves.

Comment: Can you please specify why you have cited this paper? I do have this paper, but I understand it to be a comparison of Nagoya-III, double half-helix,  and phased double half-helix antennas. It does not appear to explain why a monofilar antenna wouldn't work or specifically why the Nagoya-III and half-helix antennas do.

Comment: because you asked this "Why is a helicon wave capable of being launched with the other antennas but not a multi-loop (helical) antenna? What makes those antennas special?"; this is a bifilar helical multiloop antenna.

Comment: But it doesn't explain why a monofilar does not work which is primary point of the question. I should further clarify that a monofilar multiloop antenna would refer to simple multi-wind coil. From that clarification a double half-helix (two half-helix 180 degrees opposed) is not a multiloop antenna.

Comment: A single or multi-loop inductor is a dipole radiator and has a very broad omni- directional radiation pattern in the horizontal plane very different from that of a *helical* antenna (monofilar or bifilar) that can be excited to radiate in a more directional end-fired mode. A multiloop inductor is cursed with a rather large stray capacitance between the neighboring loops. The beauty of the bifilar helical antenna that it does not need a ground plane and it also has larger radiation resistance than the monofilar one, see,   Rowe: Nonlinear Electron-Wave Interaction Phenomena, pp571-573

Comment: https://archive.org/details/nonlinearelectro0000rowe/page/572/mode/2up